Evaluating $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^2(x^2-1)} \, dx$ at Its Upper Boundary
Background:
$$
\mbox{I am trying to solve the following integral:}\quad
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{x^{2}\left(x^{2} - 1\right)}\,{\rm d}x
$$
This is a follow-up question from this post, and the indefinite integral of said integral was answered by Claude Leibovici with the following answer:
$\int\frac{\log (x)}{x^2 \left(x^2-1\right)}\,dx = f(x) = -\frac{1}{2} [\text{Li}_2(1-x)+\text{Li}_2(-x)]-\frac{1}{2} \log (x+1) \log (x)+\frac{\log (x)}{x}+\frac{1}{x}.$
I am new to the dilogarithm, so I studied some of its identities, which are:
$\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(-x)=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Li}_2(x^2),\\
&\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{\log^2(x)}{2},\\
&\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(x)\log(1-x),\\&\mathrm{Li}_2(-x)-\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x^2)=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\log(x)\log(x+1),\\
&\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\log^2(-x)}{2}.
\end{align*}$
I also know that
$\begin{align*}
& \mathrm{Li}_2(0) = 0,\\
& \mathrm{Li}_2(1) = \frac{\pi^2}{6},\\
& \mathrm{Li}_2(-1) = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{align*}$
Question
So, I am now trying to prove that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$
To be more precise, I am trying to show that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[ \mathrm{Li}_2(1-x) + \mathrm{Li}_2(-x) + \log(x) \log(x+1) \right] = -\frac{\pi^2}{3}. \tag{1}$
I have proved that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{24}+1$,
but I still can't figure out how to use the dilogarithm identities to prove equation (1). Can anyone help me with this problem?

@Gwen I believe that your input is slightly incorrect. With the correct syntax, Wolfram shows the limit to be $-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$, as shown here.

Ah okay, Got it, deleting my reply

We can use these identities:
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(-x)=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Li}_2(x^2) \tag{1} \\
&\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(x)\log(1-x)\tag{2} \\
&\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\log^2(-x)}{2} \tag{3}.
\end{align*}
We can suppose that $x>1$. Additionally, take the principal value of $\log(x)=\ln|x|+i\arg(x)$ i.e. $-\pi<\arg(x)\leq \pi$.
Then equations (3) and (2) become:
$$ \mathrm{Li}_2(x) + \mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)-i\pi\ln(x) \tag{4}$$
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln(x)\ln(x-1)-i\pi\ln(x) \tag{5}$$
Adding equations (1) and (5):
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(-x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)=-2\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Li}_2(x^2)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln(x)\ln(x-1)-i\pi\ln(x) \tag{6}$$
From equation (4):
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)  = -\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)-i\pi\ln(x) \tag{7} $$
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x^2)  = -\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{3}-2\ln^2(x)-2i\pi\ln(x) \tag{8}$$
Substituting (7) and (8) in (6):
$$ \mathrm{Li}_2(-x) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1-x) = -\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+2\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\ln(x)\ln(x-1)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$
Hence, adding $\ln(x)\ln(x+1)$:
$$ \mathrm{Li}_2(-x) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1-x) + \ln(x)\ln(x+1) = -\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+2\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x-1}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$
Given that $\mathrm{Li}_{2}$ is continuous $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)$ then $\displaystyle \mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right),\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$
Additionally, due to the L'Hopital rule:
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x-1}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x-1}\right)}{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}} = 0 $$
$$ \boxed{\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\mathrm{Li}_2(-x) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1-x) + \ln(x)\ln(x+1) \right]= -\frac{\pi^2}{3}}$$

Thank you very much for your answer, @Bertrand87 ! However, I would like to ask one question. How did you get to the equation right after "From (1), (2), and (4):"? I have tried so many times, and with many combinations, to get what you got. Do you mind giving me a hint so I could arrive to the same conclusion? Thanks in advance!

Update: Letting eq. ($n$) equal to $f_n(x)$ for $n=1,2,4$, I obtained a result similar to yours: $f_1(x) + f_2(x) + \frac{1}{2}f_4(x^2) - 2f_4(x) = \mathrm{Li}_2(-x) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1-x) = -\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) + 2 \mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \log(x)\log(1-x) - \frac{\pi^2}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\log^2(x^2) - \frac{i \pi}{2} \log(x^2) + \log^2(x) + 2i \pi \log(x)$. Am I on the correct path? If so, what can I do to this expression to make it equivalent to yours?

@Karel it seems good, just notice that in  $\ln(1-x)$, $1-x<0$ as $x \to \infty$ so $\log(1-x)=\ln|1-x|+i\pi$. I’m using the notation $\log$ for the complex logarithm and $\ln$ for the real one. The terms $i\pi\ln(x)$ should vanish.

Oh, that's right! Awesome! But, what about the term $\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)$? It's not supposed to vanish, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

@Karel Your term is $\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x^2) = 2\ln^2(x)$ and it should cancel with other $\ln^2(x)$ terms. I will add more context to my solution to clarify these issues.

Oh that's right.. I calculated wrongly. I calculated $\frac{1}{4}\ln^2(x^2)$ as $\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)$ instead of $\ln^2(x)$. Silly me... Thank you so much for the correction! I also appreciate your effort to add more context to your solution. I will be accepting your answer, because I really love your solution — detailed and concise! Cheers!

@Karel Thanks for the acceptance, I added more steps and context. Cheers


Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined for all positive real $x$ by
$$f{\left(x\right)}:=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-x\right)}+\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1+x\right)}.$$
The particular value of $f$ at one is
$$f{\left(1\right)}=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}.$$
Computing the derivative of $f$, we find
$$\begin{align}
f^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-x\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-x\right)}+\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1+x\right)}\right]\\
&=\left[\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}-\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}+\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}+\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1+x}\right]\\
&=\frac{2\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x^{2}}.\\
\end{align}$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$f{\left(x\right)}-f{\left(1\right)}=\int_{1}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,f^{\prime}{\left(y\right)};~~~\small{x>0}.$$
Using the FTC to express $f$ as an integral, we then obtain the following result for positive real $x$:
$$\begin{align}
f{\left(x\right)}
&=f{\left(1\right)}+\int_{1}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,f^{\prime}{\left(y\right)}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\int_{1}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2\ln{\left(y\right)}}{1-y^{2}}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\int_{0}^{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)}}{t};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right]}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\int_{0}^{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+t\right)}-\ln{\left(1-t\right)}}{t}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\int_{0}^{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(t\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-t\right)}\right]\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$
In this form, the limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to infinity is now extremely straightforward to calculate:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f{\left(x\right)}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}\right]\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$


Wonderful! I really love this solution as well. Thank you, @DavidH !

This answer will be brief.
The series expansion of $log(x)log(x+1)$ at $\infty$ is:
$$log^2(x)+\frac{log(x)}{x}-\frac{log(x)}{2x^2}+O(\frac{1}{x^3})$$
The series expansion of $Li_2(-x)$ at $\infty$ is:
$${-log^2(x)}/{2}-{\pi^2}/{6}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{4x^2}+O(\frac{1}{x^3})$$
The series expansion of $Li_2(1-x)$ at $\infty$ is:
$$-\pi^2/6-log^2(x)/2+\frac{log(x)+1}{x}+\frac{2log(x)+1}{4x^2}+O(\frac{1}{x^3})$$
Which means we are interested in the first term of the series.
Basic calculation gives:
$$\lim_{x->{\infty}}[Li_2(1-x)+Li_2(-x)+log(x)log(x+1)]=-\pi^2/3$$

Thank you for your response! However, I've accepted @Bertrand87's answer as it gives a more detailed explanation. Nonetheless, I think it's interesting that you approached the problem using series expansions.
